# How can I get client machine user login in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, local

On **Localhost** my username is 'MTA' when calling this code:

```
string opl = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
TextBox1.Text = opl.Substring(opl.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

OR this code:

```
string opl = System.Environment.UserName.ToString();
TextBox1.Text = opl.Substring(opl.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

But after publishing and accessing the website from a Windows Server. My username is now 'SRVCMAN'.

Comment: I just need to know the user that is using my website.

Comment: But different persons can have the same username on different devices .. What is the benefit of getting the username here ?

Comment: It doesn't matter on which device he is, as long as I can get his username. I developed a helpdesk app (for the IT department of an enterprise) in asp.net. And the app has to automatically identify who is using it. So that the user won't have to select his name again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for implementing *Windows Authentication Mode*.
Refer to the following articles and read about it:

- [How To: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)
- [Explained: Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx)
- [How to implement Windows authentication and authorization in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323176)
- [Authenticating Users with Windows Authentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-vb)

Comment: I don't think so he is talking about Windows Authetication.

Comment: Note that to implement the above, you'll need to configure your web site to use integrated security in IIS.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: He wants to authenticate a user in an enterprise without making him providing his username and password. I think Windows Authentication is a good choice for such a case.

Comment: may be, but from his question nothing cleared what he want. But I know the way and implemnented in one of my application the way you answered and I have code as well, but I thought he just need the username only from not authentication from his question. That's why I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4):

For this to work go into IIS click on `Authentication` and disable `Anonymous Authentication` and enable `Windows Authentication`

And then use this code:

```
var ident = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
If(!ident.IsAnonymous && ident.IsAuthenticated)
{
  var loginUsername = ident.Name;
}
```

Comment: Where can I find Authentication?

Comment: @BadaBoom Open IIS and click on your Site on the left the click on Authentication in the middle beneath the IIS category.

Answer (score 4):

```
    // will return the host name making the request

    string s = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] ;
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // will return the computer name

    string s = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] ;
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //will return Windows account for the user.

    string s = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"] ;
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**I think you try to get information like this:**

[IIS Server Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)